# run a function just once in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that when someone enters a number in the textbox and when I click the search button, the function returns an image!my problem is when for the first time I click the search button, everything is ok,but when I click the button twice, again the same picture emerge in my form.How can I run just once for every input?Here is my code

```
function search() { 
  var numberEntered = document.getElementById('cpersoneli').value;
    if(numberEntered.length >=3) { 
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "image/"+ cpersoneli.value+".jpg";  
      img.id='img1';
      document.body.appendChild(img);  
    }
  else {
  alert(" Error Message");
  return false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: How is `search` being called?

Comment: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). You have to use `addEventListener` to add `click` event to your input and when you click said input then you invode `removeEventListener` on this particular input. This will prevent from invoking this function on same input more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `id` for new image, you can check if such image already exits and reuse it:

```js
function search() {
  var numberEntered = document.getElementById('cpersoneli').value;
  if (numberEntered.length >= 3) {
    const imgExists = document.getElementById("img1"), //get existing image
          img = imgExists || document.createElement('img');

    img.src = "image/" + cpersoneli.value + ".jpg";
    img.id = 'img1';
    if (!imgExists)
      document.body.appendChild(img);

  } else {
    alert(" Error Message");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="cpersoneli">
<button onclick="search()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to control the times that function is called and how many times you allow that this function can be called. This way you can perform modifications and your code will be more maintainable (if now you need that this function could be called more than 1 time, just change the `ALLOWED_TIMES` variable).

```
const ALLOWED_TIMES = 1;
let CALLED_TIMES = 0;

function search() {
  if (ALLOWED_TIMES <= CALLED_TIMES) return;

  const numberEntered = document.getElementById('cpersoneli').value;
    if(numberEntered.length >=3) { 
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "image/"+ cpersoneli.value+".jpg";  
      img.id='img1';
      document.body.appendChild(img);  
      CALLED_TIMES++;
    }
  else {
  alert(" Error Message");
  return false;
  } 
}
```

Also, avoid to user `var`, prefer to use `const` (when the variable will not be modified) or `let` (when the variable does modify the value) read more about [Hoisting on Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Comment: there is a problem with your code.it worked but when I click the button again I receive the error message

Comment: I changed the code, so that way you don't receive the error message again. The verification is now at the beginning of the code and if it doesn't attend to the condition all the code below isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating an image with a particular ID you can just test that it doesn't already exist in an if statement:

```
function search() { 
    if(document.getElementById('img1')) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will show an error message when clicked second time.